# Route to a static page in phoenix-framework

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to run an angularJS front end with a phoenix backend for my site.  I would like my root route to direct the user to a pre-built page in the static directory which contains my angular client and then use phoenix to run the API.  I have done this in the past with ruby on rails by route matching like this:

```
get '/', to: redirect('/foobar.html')
```

Is there a way to do something similar with phoenix?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not right now. You need to create a controller and then in the controller:

```
defmodule MyApp.RootController do
  use MyApp.Web, :controller

  plug :action

  def index(conn, _params) do
    redirect conn, to: "/foobar.html"
  end
end
```

Comment: @jose-valim I'm a complete newbie. I created `root_controller.ex` which the above (with elm == foobar), added `get "/elm", RootController, :index` to router.ex, and put `elm.html` in `/priv/static` and in `/web/static` but all I get is `no route found for GET /elm.html (JwtExample.Router)`. Can you expand your answer

Comment: Modern front-end frameworks such as AngularJS, React or Vue.js use an elaborated router mechanism. These routing systems need to get an `index.html` served. I believe this was the intend of the original question. The provided answer is not working because it sends an HTTP redirect. The following answer works : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37924522/render-static-html-page-in-a-controller.

Comment: Jose - given the age of this answer, be grateful if you could share any news on whether there is a better way 3 years later? Thanks for any pointers - Elixir & Phoenix are excellent - the question must be a commonly needed solution given prevalence of SPAs.

Comment: No, no alternative yet. Someone could try a feature request on Phoenix.

Answer (score 1):

In production, many people use nginx or other servers in from of their app and these servers should handle static assets. Finding the index can be done with a location rule such as:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html @proxy;
}
```

Otherwise, here's a solution that maps a request to the root path to index.html with a short function plug that can be added to your `endpoint.ex` without involving controllers:

```
def redirect_index(conn = %Plug.Conn{path_info: []}, _opts) do
    %Plug.Conn{conn | path_info: ["index.html"]}
end

def redirect_index(conn, _opts) do
    conn
end

plug :redirect_index

# This is Phoenix's standard configuration of Plug.Static with
# index.html added.

plug Plug.Static,  
    at: "/", from: :phoenix_elm_starter_template, gzip: false,
    only: ~w(css fonts index.html images js favicon.ico robots.txt)
```

Comment: Is there a solution for a dev environment where you don't have an nginx frontend?

Comment: Sure, the one that starts at "Otherwise..."

Answer (score 1):

From Jose's answer, I would modify it a little so it serves the `index.html` file directly instead of sending a `3xx` HTTP response.

```
defmodule MyApp.RootController do
  use MyApp.Web, :controller

  plug :action

  def index(conn, _params) do
    conn
    |> put_resp_header("content-type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")
    |> Plug.Conn.send_file(200, "priv/static/index.html")
  end
end
```