# Static HTML page in Phoenix

Tags: html, json, phoenix-framework, elm

I'm trying to build a JSON backend for Elm. I only want to serve one page - elm.html, one js file - Main.js - and one css file.

I tried [following these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29919143/route-to-a-static-page-in-phoenix-framework/30032537) but there is not enough there to help  a complete newbie like me.

So now I have router.ex

```
  scope "/", JwtExample do
    pipe_through :browser # Use the default browser stack

    get "/elm", RootController, :index
    get "/", PageController, :index
  end


  # Other scopes may use custom stacks.
  scope "/api", JwtExample do
    pipe_through :api

    resources "/users", UserController, except: [:new, :edit]
  end
```

This controller

```
defmodule JwtExample.RootController do
  use JwtExample.Web, :controller

  plug :action

  def index(conn, _params) do
    redirect conn, to: "/elm.html"
  end
end
```

And my files in `web/static` and `priv/static`

But when I surf to /elm I get

> no route found for GET /elm.html (JwtExample.Router)

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35100117/how-to-serve-static-page-in-phoenix-framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so based on psantos answer, I needed to change lib/endpoint.ex to read

```
  plug Plug.Static,
    at: "/", from: :jwt_example, gzip: false,
    only: ~w(css fonts images js favicon.ico robots.txt elm.html)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that also servers the static page for requests to the root url, i. e. https://myapp.test/:

here's a solution that maps a request to the root path to index.html with a short function plug that can be added to your `endpoint.ex` without involving controllers. It works by defining a short Plug function to change the requested path. My hope is that it's a little faster to to it in the endpoint compared to doing it in a controller.

```
def redirect_index(conn = %Plug.Conn{path_info: []}, _opts) do
    %Plug.Conn{conn | path_info: ["elm.html"]}
end

def redirect_index(conn, _opts) do
    conn
end

plug :redirect_index

# This is Phoenix's standard configuration of Plug.Static with
# index.html added.

plug Plug.Static,  
    at: "/", from: :phoenix_elm_starter_template, gzip: false,
    only: ~w(css fonts elm.html images js favicon.ico robots.txt)
```

Note that in production, you would usually deal with static assets at application server layer, possibly not hitting Phoenix at all.