# Render static html page in a controller

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Is there a way to read and render a static html file located at 
another part on server in the controller ? I am not looking to redirect or serve this page via static pages functionality.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use [`Plug.Conn.send_file/5`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#send_file/5) for this. This function will send the contents of the file more efficiently than reading the whole file into memory and then sending it using `Phoenix.Controller.html/2`:

```
conn
|> put_resp_header("content-type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")
|> Plug.Conn.send_file(200, "/path/to/html")
```

Note that I had to manually add the `content-type` header to get the same behavior as `Phoenix.Controller.html/2`.

Comment: If the file you want to send is distributed with the application itself, you don't want to hardcode the full path to the file, as it may change. Instead you should put the file in the `priv` directory and pass `Application.app_dir(:your_app, "priv/path/to/file")` as the path in `send_file/3`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Phoenix.Controller.html/2](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html#html/2) function for send custom  html content. Read the the file with [File.read!/2](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/File.html#read!/1) and send the content to the client.

```
def index(conn, _params) do
  html(conn, File.read!("path/to/file.html"))
end
```

Hope this helps.