# Serving a SPA via Plug.Conn.send_file

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm serving my SPA through Phoenix following the resolution here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37924920/15064

When I move to a release build, the spa winds up in a directory with a versioned name, eg:
`/opt/appname/lib/appname-0.0.1/priv/static/index.html`

This seems like a brittle approach as a new version would cause this link to break every time a new version of the app is released.

Is there anyway to serve the app from a relative path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is in a `priv` for `app_name` directory, you can do:

```
Application.app_dir(:app_name, "priv/static/index.html")
```

And this will return a full path based on the `app_name` location, which should work even if you move the project around.